# Magento 1.7.0.2 and 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access */index.php on this server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento-1.7, php-5.3, http-status-code-403

we just moved our Magento 1.7.0.2 shop from one server to the other. We did the following:

- In root folder we adjusted rewrite base in .htaccess
- We activated "using rewrite url" in System=>Configuration=>General=>Web

But now every time we open any link (e.g. domain.com/about) we get following error:

403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /var/www/***/index.php on this server.
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at www.domain.com Port 80

Only start page can be opened. If we turn off "using rewrite url" in System=>Configuration=>General=>Web everything works again, but then any URL has an index.php included e.g. domain.com/index.php/about. We use hosted vServer with Confixx 3pro as server management software. WebServer mod_rewrite is activated for every user in Confixx user management. register_globals, safe_mode, and open_basedir are tuned off for all users.

We checked all file permissions with standard magento-check.php and also checked user with chown command via ssh several times. All mandatory files are writable and are owned by necessary user.

Do you have any idea how we can fix this? Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Marcus

Comment: Paste your .htaccess file in the question.